# Wicket 8 ClientProperties some Methods deprecated

Tags: wicket, wicket-8

I recently upgraded from Wicket 7.x to 8.1.0 and wondered what happens to some of the `ClientProperties` methods, that are now marked `@Deprecated` without a hint why or what will become of them.
The migration guide doesn't mention them either.
I found [this commit](https://github.com/apache/wicket/commit/ba3a4bfde623c9a68533d6eda9c65034cb8ee8ce#diff-963e345762cf0122b21e42808459245c) introducing the changes, but couldn't trace it back to a Jira story (WICKET-6544 is about buggy user agent detection, i don't see the link here).

So what will become of this feature, will it be removed without replacement?

Comment: FYI: The link beteen the two is that ClientProperties is based on browser (user agent) detection which is buggy. (Always has been buggy, always will be buggy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question: User agent detection was indeed deprecated in Wicket 8 and will be removed in Wicket 9.

I've updated the migration guides, users are encouraged to switch to specialized libraries like https://github.com/nielsbasjes/yauaa now.